# Allowing a connection to communicate with my .NET Restful API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api

So, I am building a RESTFUL API using the .NET framework. However, I have come to a stand still because the connections are getting denied. It is rejecting self signed certificates.

So I am using a mobile hot spot (so I can check over several connections), Where my phone is trying to connect to the API. It gets Rejected. I have Unity trying to connect from the same device the API server is running, it gets denied. I use postman on local system, it gets denied. If I turn off the SSL Certificate in postman... huzzah it works! However, I do not like this. Or perhaps I am confused on how to set this up properly.

I am using the come-out-of-the-box API .NET provides you, with some touches:

```cs
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<Player> Get()
 {
   Player player = new Player
   {
     Id = 1,
     Name = "Bloodmorphed"
    };
    return player;
 }
```

Now in Unity (as its really the only code i've written to GET the data):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Net;

public class CallAPI : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetUnityWebRequest());
    }

    IEnumerator GetUnityWebRequest()
    {
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://localhost:44305/api/values");
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if (request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("HTTP Error: " + request.error);
        }
        else if (request.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Network Error: " + request.error);
        }
        else if (request.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Other Error: " + request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, with Unity, it will give an network error, but says "Unknown Error". I can force it to not use a self signed certificate, but I think this would be better fixed server side rather than client side.

So: It works on a local browser, down not work on a remote browser but on same network (I know it connect as i've done this before... its rejecting the connection). It will work on postman if i disable the ssl certificate. I am a bit at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to call an httpS url when in dev it would be better to call an http (no S) url. If you go live with your app, then consider switching to encrypted communications, but using the secure version of http (https) is a bit overkill for local testing

Comment: I would agree, but it doesn't let me use just http, for some reason. EDIT: NVM I am an idiot. I just had to comment out the auto redirect.

Comment: What error does it get you when you try with just http?

Comment: please post this as a comment. it's not an answer

Comment: Oh didn’t know. Not sure I understand though, can you clarify why?